# How to make text center in Hero image with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to model the following design with Bootstrap.

[image]

Currently I've found a method to do this using "carousel-caption" class from bootstrap CSS but it doesn't seem to working as expected.

The html looks like this:

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x550" alt="test" class="img-responsive">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Text word1 word2 superlative.</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You can see an example of on https://jsfiddle.net/3vf5gog4/2/

This produces a single title but the image doesn't stretch and the title is not vertically centered and I can't figure out how I should be adding another title beneath the current carousel title

Comment: Add `col-xs-12` class to your `img-responsive` to fix the image, as of `carousel-caption` it's vertically aligned in the bottom not middle

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those things with bootstrap that can trip you up. So the `.container-fluid` class has a padding around it and so to the other grid elements so thats causing the issues with the stretch.  Vertically centred elements in CSS can be a pain there is [one good method](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) I've seen on it but I typically just eye ball the percent and add some precent

I've edited your fiddle to take out the bootstrap padding and centre that text.
https://jsfiddle.net/3vf5gog4/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
.carousel-caption{
  postion:absolute;
  top : 20%;
}
```